# How to obtain the target path pointed by a symbolic link in Tcl

Tags: tcl, symlink

I need to find the path of the target file pointed by a symbolic link in tcl. ie. if C:\temp\link is a symbolic link file pointed to the target C:\bin\sub\sub1\originalfile , how can we find the path C:\bin\sub\sub1\originalfile from the symbolic link file C:\temp\link using Tcl?
i used

```
 set item "C:\temp\link"
    file readlink $item
```

But it returned the following error

```
could not readlink "C:/temp/link": not a directory
```

Can anyone help?

Comment: Sounds like `file readlink` only handles NTFS junctions, not the newer symlink reparse points.

Comment: @scherlek How to deal with symbolic links in tcl?

Comment: Is that an actual symbolic link or is it a [file shortcut](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_shortcut#Microsoft_Windows)?

Comment: @glennjackman I created it in tcl itself using the command < file link {C:\temp\link} {C:\bin\sub\sub1\originalfile} >

Comment: It is a known bug: [ticket](http://core.tcl.tk/tcl/tktview/c8d4f01a54d7ecf819f4881fb02467ad14fc7b0c)

Comment: Actually when I created the link in Tcl, i didnt specify the link type. So i think it created a hard link. becoz when i specify the link type explicitly as -symbolic, it generates an error "could not create new link "C:\temp\link" pointing to "C:\bin\sub\sub1\originalfile": not a directory.....Do anyone know the reason? I am using Windows OS....Does that cause the error?

Comment: Open bug is open bug; what it says on the tin.

Answer (score 1):

There's a trick to handle this problem. It is introduced by the Tcler's Wiki: https://wiki.tcl-lang.org/page/file+normalize, by just appending */something* at the end of the path of your symbol link file.

Below I post their original words:

> **Resolving symlinks in the last component of a path**
>
> To resolve symlinks
> in a path's final component (i.e., the target file or directory name
> itself) you can use the following trick: add /something to the path
> before normalizing it then strip the extra component away with file
> dirname.
>
> For example,
>
> `set resolvedArgv0 [file dirname [file normalize $argv0/___]]]`
>
> *dbohdan 2015-05-12: This trick was implemented by AK in Tclssg's main > procedure  and I thought it deserved wider exposure. The credit is all AK's.*
>
> *PYK 2015-05-12: This technique is also employed in main script.*